# localhost wordpress redirects to XAMPP Site

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, localhost

my localhost in my browser keeps redirects to Welcome to XAMPP for Windows!

I have set the necessary at database url at wpe2_options, wpe2_posts , wpe2_postmeta

htaccss

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

but it doesnt seems to work, when i clicked the a link it keeps directing to the welcome xampp.

even tried Virtual Host,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\site1"
ServerName site1.localhost 
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\site1">
DirectoryIndex index.php
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

this cause other localhost site redirecting to site1(wordpress)

Please help.

Answer (score 6):

Please check your .htaccess file, hope the below code solve your issue :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site1/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /site1/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: i tried but the following subsite not showing.Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ramcreditinfo3/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^search-corporate-profile/? /buy.ramcreditinfo/search-corporate-profile [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /ramcreditinfo3/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Answer (score 0):

Open wp-config.php file in the WordPress folder, and set following parameter.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

Was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9764745/3046656).

Check your wp-options table and find all occurrence of 'localhost' in option_value field

http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_options

```
SELECT * from wp_options where option_value like '%localhost%';
```

and change those to your live URL and you should be set